# How to make an automated/ predetermined user prompt selection in a bash script

Tags: bash, terminal, scripting

I am making a bash terminal server startup script. One of the commands runs some commands of its own and then presents a user prompt selection:

```
? Select a pod  [Use arrows to move, type to filter]
> mypodA-c77889b9-4q5rv
  mypodB-7975dfcf5-6tcnv
```

I tried to add `echo mypodA\n` to simulate the selection of the first option, but that does not work. Can this be done? Any suggestions how?

Comment: @Inian Uh, I am not interested in making a menu, but in how to make an automated pick from a cli menu...?!

Comment: you can use `expect` for interactivity with your script

Comment: @Ardit yeah, that looks nice! Do you know how to script my case with `expect` as only the `myPodA` and `myPodB` parts of my selection are know in advance? As the selection menu 'filters'  maybe that helps?

Comment: can you post the full command you are running?